# How to set header in robot framework for HttpLibrary.HTTP

Tags: robotframework

How to set the header as content-type and authentication for robotframework

```
*** Variables ***

${PORT}     36504
${HOST}     https://staging-product..co/api/products
${HeaderName}     Content-Type
${HeaderValue}     application/json
${HeaderName1}     Authorization
${HeaderValue1}     Token token=zkzg1VPnhcMm7uv,email=cctest7@gmail.com


*** Settings ***

Resource        variables.txt
Library         HttpLibrary.HTTP
Test Setup      Create HTTP Context  ${HOST}    https

*** Test Cases ***
Set Headers
    POST      https://staging-product..co/api/products

Full-URL GET to MytestSsite
    GET      https://staging-product.connect.co/
```

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the HTTP Library Documentation (https://peritus.github.io/robotframework-httplibrary/HttpLibrary.html)

Set Request Header  |    header_name, header_value  |
Sets a request header for the next request.

header_name is the name of the header, e.g. User-Agent header_value is the key of the header, e.g. RobotFramework HttpLibrary (Mozilla/4.0)

A further simple example would be:

```
Set Request Header  Content-Type    application/json
```

or using your variables above:

```
Set Request Header  ${HeaderName}   ${HeaderValue}
```

Here is a full example:

```
Create HTTP Context    ${HOST}    http
${Request_Body}    Get File    ${xmlFilename}    encoding=${Request_Body_Encoding}
Set Request Header    ${HeaderName}    ${HeaderValue}
Set Request Body    ${Request_Body}
Log    ${Request_Body}
POST    ${URL}
Response Status Code Should Equal    ${ResponseStatusCode}
```

Comment: can you please provide a simple please

Comment: I've added an example, please read the docs however, they really do explain it all quite clearly.  Worst case you can read the source code on github.

Comment: Actually I need a complete demo file .. I have seen this in documentation but it was not help me out as I am new for robotclass .. I am facing issue like what should be first .. URL or header etc

Comment: what is above and in the docs shows you absolutely everything you need, if it isn't enough, you simply are not trying.  What issue have you hit exactly?  I've added a full and final example above.

Comment: @ShubhamJain please accept the answer if this helped